# Center vertically menu icon in Chrome for Mobile

Tags: css, google-chrome, mobile, center

I have a menu icon that's perfectly vertically centered in all browsers but in Chrome for Mobile not. This is the code for the menu icon:

-HTML-

```
<div class="menuIcon">
  <p class="im im-menu"></p>
</div>
```

-CSS-

```
.menuIcon{
    border: 2px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding: 2px 6px;
    color: #424242;
    transition: background-color 0.8s ease 0s;
}   
.menuIcon:hover{
    background-color: #ddd;
}
.im {
  display: inline-block;
  font: normal normal normal 24px/1 'iconmonstr-iconic-font';
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

I tried with `line-height: 24px` and other properties but with no result. With `padding: 6px 2px 2px` is more or less centered in Chrome for Mobile but in desktop browsers is malformed so it's not an option. If someone could also explain me this behaviour I will be very grateful.

Here's the [link](http://tanie-przeprowadzki-warszawa.pl/) to my website. Remember that the problem is only in Chrome for Mobile.

I upload a screenshot of the problem.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: this doesn't seem to be happening on my chrome + mobile

Comment: sorry it is not clear what you are talking about. Can you provide screenshot of the issue

Comment: @viCky of course I already uploaded a screenshot, the menu icon is at the right of the image. The menu icon (the three lines) in desktop browsers is vertically centered but not in Chrome for Mobile.

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa I have uploaded a screenshot of how it looks in my Chrome for Mobile

Comment: i don't see it sticking to the top in the screenshot.

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa I explained myself badly. I mean that the icon is not vertically centered inside it's borders.

Comment: Hmmm, thats weird, mine is perfectly centered within the border when i view on my chrome's "mobile mode".

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa maybe is another version

Comment: and which chrome version is yours ?

Comment: I'm using Chrome 59